# How to remove the row from the datagridview?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, row

my table is that

```
Joe          Jackson            200
Jackson      Sue                200
```

my code is that

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < dataGridView1.RowCount; j++)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value == dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value)
        {
            int miktar_alici = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
            int miktar_satici = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value);
            if (miktar_alici == miktar_satici)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Index);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I want my code to output something like this:

```
 Joe Sue   200
```

only one row. But  the code has an error from the "RemoveAt" line. How can I fix that?

Comment: What error are you getting? Or you want us to take a wild guess?

Comment: `RowCount` decreases every time you remove a row, but the iterator (i, j) keeps increasing so eventually you try to access a row index that doesn't exist. Also, I think you want to iterate over cells in the nested loop, not rows again.

Comment: My error is: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: The new unsaved line can not be deleted.

Comment: if you remove items from a collection through which you iterate, you need a reverse loop: start from the end and run until `0`.

Comment: Also, what do you expect to happen when : `i` equals 1 and `j` equals 1, `i` equals 2 and `j` equals 2, and more generally when `i` equals `j` ? You are removing almost every row of your datagrid and trying to remove rows outside the range of it

Comment: i did it. Thanks for everyone. I started fro the end @MongZhu

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is bigger than just iterating from the start instead of iterating from the end when you want to remove rows from your grid.

Let's say you did this :

```
for (int i = dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    for (int j = dataGridView1.RowCount - 2; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value == dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value)
        {
            int miktar_alici = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
            int miktar_satici = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value);
            if (miktar_alici == miktar_satici)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Index);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Well then I can assure you that almost every rows of your grid are going to be removed.

Indeed, you would keep iterating through all rows but the last with `j`, so for every `i` in this range, there will be an iteration where `i == j`.

Therefore, `miktar_alici` will be equal to `miktar_satici` and you will remove the row.

In the end, only the last row will remain, and I'm quite sure it isn't the behaviour you want.

Now, instead of using `RowCount` for `j`, you should start at `i - 1`. This way you won't compare again a row with all the rows you previously iterated with `i`, and you will never have `i == j`.

```
for (int i = dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
```